# System.Xml.XmlDocument amazon s3 equivalent for .net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I am new to amazon s3 and was trying to change a legacy code method to the s3 equivalent. The code is something like this:

```
public static System.Xml.XmlDocument GetXmlDocument(string path)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    using (UNCAccess ua = new UNCAccess(GetDirectoryPath(path)))
    {
        if (FileExists(path)) xmlDoc.Load(path);
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

I have changed the above code to something like this:

```
public static System.Xml.XmlDocument GetXmlDocument(string path, string key)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    AWSS3File aws = new AWSS3File();
    path = path.Replace("\\", "/");
    path = path.Replace(aws.awsBucketName + "/", "");
    if (!aws.DirectoryExists(path))
    {
        using (aws.client = aws.GetS3Client())
        {
            if (aws.FileExists(key))
                xmlDoc.Load(path);
        }
    }
    return xmlDoc;

    //System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    //using (UNCAccess ua = new UNCAccess(GetDirectoryPath(path)))
    //{
    //    if (FileExists(path)) xmlDoc.Load(path);
    //}
    //return xmlDoc;
}
```

But since the return type here is a system return type it doesn't fit with s3. I just wanna know if there is an s3 equivalent return type for xml document?

Any suggestions are welcome and thank you in advance :)

Comment: "But since the return type here is a system return type it doesn't fit with s3." I really don't see what you mean. I wouldn't expect using AWS to mean "never use any types defined in the BCL". (I would use a `using` directive for `System.Xml` to avoid all those horrible fully-qualified names, and I'd personally use LINQ to XML instead, but those are different matters.) What *exactly* do you mean by "it doesn't fit with s3"?

Comment: Oops my bad..i meant since the class here used is System.Xml.XmlDocument is there an equivalent s3 class that can be used or should i be doing what you just said? For example for getting a fileinfo in s3 there is S3FileInfo class that can be used in the method defintion.

Comment: Why would you expect there to be an equivalent S3 class? It's an XML document - there's no need for an S3-specific class here. Reading a file from S3 is different from reading a file from the local disk - but you've got an *entirely local object* when you've loaded the data into an XML document. Would you expect an S3String class, and an S3Int32 struct?

Comment: It will be a S3Int32 struct.

Comment: You would *really* expect there to be an equivalent of `System.Int32`, which behaves exactly the same way in every respect except performance (because the CLR won't know about it), just for the sake of having an S3 prefix in the same? A 32-bit signed integer doesn't behave any differently just because it "came from Amazon". I think you need to step back and consider *why* you want there to be different types for everything - and what that means for interoperating with other code which *isn't* Amazon-specific.

Comment: Alright Thank You for your time :) So that means i would have to look towards linq to xml or use the using directive as suggested by you earlier to tackle this?